# AngularJS - Get $cookies instance outside of controller

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm doing some session storing with cookies using Angular.

I have no problem getting the $cookies instance to work when i'm inside the scope of the controller:

```
MyApp.controller('ValidationController',['$cookies', validateUser]);
function validateUser($cookies)
{
    //some logic with the $cookies instance
}
```

But is there a way to receive a singleton instance of $cookies? regardless to using a controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly, but you can inject `$cookie` service in any other place where it makes sense, it doesn't need to be a controller only. For example, it can be other service if you need to use it:

```
MyApp.factory('something', ['$cookie', function($cookie) {
    // use $cookie service 
}])
```

Comment: That's actually what i meant.. I not that strong in Angular yet. trying to learn as I go :)